# Typescript React HOC error with hoist-non-react-statics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm using react and typescript and hoist-non-react-statics and trying to create a HOC. I've simplified the code to just a contrived HOC that wraps the component with a div.

```
const withWrapper = <TProps extends {}>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<TProps>,
) => {
  const WithWrapper: React.FC<TProps> = (props: TProps) => (
    <div>
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    </div>
  )

  WithWrapper.displayName = `WithWrapper(${
    WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component'
  })`

  return hoistNonReactStatics(WithWrapper, WrappedComponent)
}
```

But getting the error:

```
Argument of type 'ComponentType<TProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<any>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<TProps, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<TProps, any>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<TProps, any>' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | any | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.

     return hoistNonReactStatics(WithWrapper, WrappedComponent)
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is this invalid? The only way to get it to pass is by casting `WrappedComponent as React.ComponentType<any>`.

EDIT: typescript@2.9.2
@types/react@16.8.4
@types/hoist-non-react-statics@3.0.1

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a different version of TypeScript or some of the typings? For example, if you use Visual Studio Code, you might want to select the version of TypeScript installed in your project (instead of the one built into the IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine with `typescript@3.3.1`, `@types/react@16.8.4` and `@types/hoist-non-react-statics@3.0.1`.

The only incorrect thing in your code is using a single pipe (`|`) instead of double one. A single pipe is used for bitwise OR, whereas double does short-circuiting — I believe you meant the latter.

Comment: Sorry I should have added the typescript version: 2.9.2. Edited OP. Thanks for the pipe catch, contrived example error.

Comment: I think upgrading TS is the way to go on this. Although I'd love to know why perfectly good code fails in 2.9.2